# How to import multiple json sections (all in one file) in to python/pandas

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, json-normalize

I'm trying to process a json file for use in another program that will use an excel file. My json file has multiple sections/arrays, one for some basic info like number of records, report name. It has sections/arrays for column names and then another that has each individual row/record as an array.

I've tried using pandas.read_json and the json_loads options to read the data in but I continually get errors.  If I remove all sections except just one (like the rows) section, I can get it to read that in (although it puts all columns in one column like it's not identifying each column name separated by a comma as a separate column.

Ideally I'd like to not need to manually edit this file and just process it in python into a pandas dataframe so I can further manipulate it and export it for other use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my first post so if there's anything I can do better let me know!

Here's a representation of the json data, the actual data has several more columns and many more rows/records (700+ usually)

```
{
"count": 2,
"name": "report1",
"columnNames": [
    "Incident ID",
    "Status",
    "Subject"
],
"rows": [
    [
        "2460636",
        "Resolved",
        "login help"
    ],
    [
        "2460637",
        "Unresolved",
        "email help"
    ]
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the columnNames section to become the column names in a pandas dataframe and each "row" to be a record in the dataframe.

I've tried looking at other examples but I haven't come across a similar issue with json formatted like this.

I've tried using pandas.read_json("example.json") as well as the json.loads to load the data to get it in but they all come up with different errors that I can't seem to get around.

When Running the pandas.read_json("example.json") it comes back saying "arrays must all be same length".

Result should be the columnNames section/array should be the column names of the pandas dataframe and then each "row" I want to be a record in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use `pd.json_normalize`: to unpack your `json` file

[pd.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

json_data = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

Output:

```
                       columnNames  count  name                            rows
0   [Incident ID, Status, Subject]  2   report1 [[2460636, Resolved, login help], [2460637, Un...
```

Unpack `rows`:

```
df_rows = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['rows'], meta=['name'])
df_rows.rename({0: data['columnNames'][0],
                1: data['columnNames'][1],
                2: data['columnNames'][2]}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output of `df_row`:

```
     Incident ID        Status       Subject       name
0        2460636      Resolved    login help    report1
1        2460637    Unresolved    email help    report1
```

The `json` isn't particularly well formed, something like the following would be easier to unpack:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "name": "report1",
    "rows": [{
            "Incident ID": "2460636",
            "Status": "Resolved",
            "Subject": "login help"
        }, {
            "Incident ID": "2460637",
            "Status": "Unresolved",
            "Subject": "email help"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That's awesome thank you! I updated my code and expanded it to encompass my entire json file and it works and is in a pandas dataframe now. Thank you! you were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Because I haven't seen your full json file I don't know if this will do everything you need it to do, but based on your test data this does create a pandas df with the data from a json formatted dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

test_dict={
    "count": 2,
    "name": "report1",
    "columnNames": [
        "Incident ID",
        "Status",
        "Subject"
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            "2460636",
            "Resolved",
            "login help"
        ],
        [
            "2460637",
            "Unresolved",
            "email help"
        ]
        ]
    }

def make_df(json_dat): #use this function every time you want to make new df from json
    indicent_id=[]
    status=[]
    subject=[]

    for row in json_dat.get('rows'): #loop for all rows in df and append data to lists
        indicent_id.append(row[0])
        status.append(row[1])
        subject.append(row[2])

    #create pandas df from data
    df=pd.DataFrame([indicent_id, status, subject],
                    index=['indicent_id', 'status', 'subject']).T

    return df

#you can call the function now every time you need to make a df, potentially generating a dictionary of dfs based on the name of the json files 

df1= make_df(test_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking through this now. Would there be any way instead of creating the dict in python with the json data to have it read that from a file into the dict? I will be getting this json data through an API call to an oracle report so I may not need to read from a file but would like to verify that is working as I try to get other parts of this. The error I get when I try to pass this json file in to the dict variable is "'str' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: Oh, yeah, you have to read in the json file the the `json' package. That will create a dictionary that looks just like the one you showed. You can see an [example](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python), or read the `json` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Answer (score -1):

I'm gonna give you the general approach and I think you can build on it.

- Create a pandas dataframe with three dummy column names
- Insert all the rows per your requirement.
- Rename columns using `columnNames` segment of json.

Comment: I will see if I can get it to do that. Part of the problem I'm having is getting Python to import the json file as an object that I can then get the specific section data from. I can import the file as string data but am unsure how to get the specific sections like the rows or columns section data to fill in to the data frame.